# iOS Launch Images for UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, ios4

According to the iPhone Human Interface Guidelines every app needs a launch image. My app is just a navigation controller which contains a table view. How can i simulate an empty tableview and navigation bar as per the guidelines. "Simulate Interface" in IB fills the view with the standard California data.

I tried creating a basic navigation based app and screen grabbed the interface but it wasnt the right size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A screen grab should be the right size.  Don't forget that if your image is for a retina display that you should use a name ending in `@2x.png`.

Comment: Thats a good point about iPhone 4 - if i scale up to 200% will that work? My iMac is the right size, but on my MacBook Pro where i do most of my development work, it is different.

Comment: Kind of, but it will look blocky.  Did you take a screenshot from the simulator?  If so, take one directly from the device by holding the top button while pressing the home button.

Comment: Ahhhh ok I'll do that. Since i have an iPhone 4 will that be high enough resolution then for retina display?

Comment: Yeah the iPhone 4 screenshot will give you a retina image.  Save that as your @2x image, scale it down 50%, and save that as your normal image.